# How can I create a table in Lua, then add values from the C API?

Tags: api, lua, lua-table

Here's what I have so far... It creates global table called "mod", but I can't seem to add indexes to the table...

```
lua_newtable(L);
lua_setglobal(L,"mod");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_setfield) says:

> ```
> void lua_setfield (lua_State *L, int index, const char *k);
> ```
>
> Does the equivalent to `t[k] = v`, where `t` is the value at the given valid index and `v` is the value at the top of the stack.
>
> This function pops the value from the stack.

So, more precisely: Push whatever you want to add onto the stack, then call `lua_setfield`.  For example:

```
lua_pushnumber( L, 42 );
lua_setfield( L, -2, "answer_to_life_universe_and_rest" )
```

This inserts the field "answer_to_life..." with value `42` into the table.

Comment: nvm :P I had the lines mixed up